Key Error when trying to extract layer activation in TensorFlow sequential model
I have a Sequential model that is trained on the MNIST dataset.
After training, I am trying to create a new model to output activations from the hidden ReLU (Dense) layer.
I reshaped the test image correctly but get an error when calling the predict() function on the activation model.
Here's the code I'm using to extract the activations:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers

# Load and preprocess the MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# Define and compile the model
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

# Define the activation model
layer_name = 'dense'
activation_model = models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)

However i get the following error.
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-cbfe6f9d08f9> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 # Define the activation model
     18 layer_name = 'dense'
---> 19 activation_model = models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
     20 
     21 # Prepare the test image

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py in _get_node_attribute_at_index(self, node_index, attr, attr_name)
    283         """
    284         if not self._inbound_nodes:
--> 285             raise ValueError(
    286                 f"The layer {self.name} has never been called "
    287                 f"and thus has no defined {attr_name}."

ValueError: The layer sequential_14 has never been called and thus has no defined input.

I have:

Verified that TensorFlow is properly installed.
Checked the model layers and input shapes.
Adjusted the input shape of the test image to add batch size and channels.


You have created the sequential model and trying to access the input attribute of the sequential model using functional model API which is causing the error. To avoid this error, you can create the functional model and define the layer name and then train the model. To access the model's input, you need to use model.input which only works for functional API models not in sequential model.
I am attaching gist file for your reference.
For more details refer this.

